# How to add members to a Group using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

How do I add Members to a Group via Microsoft Graph API?

According to documentation for adding Member to a particular Group, it requires the call below:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 30
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}
```

My questions lies in this API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
```

- `{id}` => the group id,
- `members` => adding members to the group

Now where is the users/members data/parameter to be added or posted?

Is it  `"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"`?

Do I post `@odata.id` values as a member/users parameter when adding a member to a group?

Answer (score 9):

That is correct. What you're technically passing is an ODATA Reference (`ref$`) to the `user` object within Active Directory rather than just an `id`.

To illustrate, lets take this fictitious `user`:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "id": "48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038",
    "businessPhones": [
        "+1 412 555 0109"
    ],
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
    "givenName": "Megan",
    "jobTitle": "Auditor",
    "mail": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": "12/1110",
    "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
    "surname": "Bowen",
    "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

If we wanted to add Megan to the a Group with an `id` of `02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315` the call would look like this:

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MeganB@M365x214355.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

Comment: Hello @MarcLaFleur Could you please help me understand $ref? Is it predefined or how can I get it? Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

It is also working when passing user Id:

```
POST url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json

Content string: {"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}"}
```

group_id - group object id

user_id - user object id

Comment: Hello @Maria Could you please help me understand $ref? Is it predefined or how can I get it?

Thank you,

Comment: $ref is static, it is not variable